# Checking a String for a particular format in Java

Tags: java, string, exception, format

I'm trying to check a String for a particular format in Java. The format must be LetterLetterNumberNumber

Example: js34

If this format is not not entered then my program will throw a format exception. For some reason I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this.
I considered using String.matches() method but I don't think it would work here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String user;

    System.out.print("Enter your String: ");
    user = (new Scanner(System.in)).nextLine();//format must match LetterLetterNumberNumber

    //format checker goes here
    
  }
}

class formatException extends Exception{

  public formatException(){
    System.out.print(toString());
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "Incorrect format!";
  }

  
}
```

Comment: That‘s a perfect use case for regular expressions, so String.matches makes sense. PS:  Class names are expected to start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment suggested, you can use String.matches() with regex. It'll look something like this:

```
    //format checker goes here
    if (!user.matches("^[A-Za-z]{2}\\d{2}$")) {
        throw new FormatException();
    }
```

I'll explain the regex. The "^" signifies that we want to match the start of the string. Then "[A-Za-z]" matches any upper- or lowercase letter. "{2}" means we want to match that two times. "\d" matches a digit. (The double backslash means we want an actual backslash and not an escape character like "\n" (newline).) Then the "{2}" again, because we want two digits. And finally "$" matches the end of the string.

Note: I made formatException start with uppercase.